# how to play .swf files in IE using iframe tag

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to play .swf files in IE using an iframe tag in jsp. But they are not playing. They are playing in Chrome & Safari. Can anyone help? The code is as follows:

```
  <iframe src="courses/slide1.swf " 
         frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="myiframe"
         width="850px" height="650px" >
  </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually flash files use the embed tag to run SWF within a browser, but I guess Chrome & Safari are playing it because they share the same engine "WebKit". I can't understand why they allow it to run within an iframe tag, I guess that will represent a security issue along the road.

Answer (score -1):

You can embed it using iframe but you need to define atributes as style

Comment: the question asks how to play in iframe, so provide a specific answer to that or else put your thoughts as comments